# Content dispute

Tags: support

I was wondering if some kind soul could explain:

- What is a 'content dispute'?
- How are content disputes resolved?
- How long should a content dispute be expected to take to resolve?
- Are there any other posts on meta where one can find out about content disputes?

Comment: Ad 1. It's something you don't want to get into. 2. By pressing the little cross at the top of the tab. 3. For what seems like forever. 4. Hmm there is this comment now...

Comment: You might like to check out the question [“This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250099/) on SE meta